# Guacamole Error: The remote desktop server is currently unreachable. If the problem persists, please notify your system administrator

Tags: docker, remote-access, guacamole

I'm installing [Apache Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/) using [DockerHub's Guacamole container](https://hub.docker.com/r/oznu/guacamole) on a macOS Big Sur laptop. From the terminal, I'm running this command:

```
docker run \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v :/config \
  oznu/guacamole
```

Then, I'm getting my `IP`'s address by typing `ipconfig getifaddr en0` in the terminal. With the `IP`'s address & port `8080`, I open my browser & navigate to `<ip-address-here>:8080/#/` which takes me to the login screen.

[image]

From there, I do the following:

- Enter the Guacamole's default `user` which it's `guacadmin` (both `username` & `password`).
- Create a new `user` with `admin'`s privileges.
- Delete the default `user` for security reasons.

Then, I create a new connection with the following parameters:

**EDIT CONNECTION**

- `Name: <connection-name>`
- `Location: ROOT`
- `Protocol: VNC`

**Network**

- `Hostname: <ip-address-here>`
- `Port: 5900` (I think this is the default port for VNC's protocol)

**Authentication**

- `Username: <machine-username-here>`
- `Password: <machine-password-here`

I hit save & try to connect, but I get to this screen:

[image]

**Note:** [I also enabled Remote Management on my Mac.](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh11851/mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Instead of enabling the Remote Management, I enabled VNC's server using [this article](https://support.jumpdesktop.com/hc/en-us/articles/216425923-Mac-How-do-I-enable-the-VNC-Server-built-into-the-Mac-).

Comment: I cannot access the link :-(